# Loop though array with arrays in it

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array with arrays in it. I need to loop through it so I have both the index as a variable, and the value as one as well.

I have run `print_r($array)` on my array and this is displayed:

```
Array
{
   [ns] => Array

    {
       [car1]=>chevy
       [car2]=>dodge
     }
    [mx] =>Array
     {
       [color1]=>red
      }
 }
```

I need the loop to display:

```
car1 chevy
car2 dodge
color1 red
```

I know I need a `foreach` loop but I can not seem to get it to work correctly.  I always get the error:

> trying to get property of non object

Comment: Show the code that's not working.

Comment: If they're arrays... don't treat them like objects.

Comment: Always post your coding attempt with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you'll find an example how to loop trough keys and values.

```
<?php
foreach($yourArr as $key => $value){
   //$key will contain ns and mx
   //$value will contain Array and Array
   //So we need to loop through $value

   foreach($value as $subKey => $subValue){
       //$subKey will contain car1, car2 and color1
       //$subValue will contain chevy, dodge, red
   }
}
```

Comment: `$key` declaration is not used/needed.

Answer (score 1):

Going through an array of arrays to get the values of the inner arrays works like this:

```
foreach($array as $row => $subArray)
{
    foreach($subArray as $subRow => $value)
    {
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not provide the desired result.